# Default View Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

Regardless of whether I save docs in the print layout view, they always open in web layout view.  They do open in 100%, which is what I want.  However, if I click on one page it converts to 78%.  I do not know how to write macros or why I should have to.  I would just like to be able to simply open each and every word doc in print layout, 100%, instead of having to go through all of the redundant steps of changing my settings with each newly opened doc.  Is this possible?